# Lyrics to the German national anthem at American wedding

Tags: lyrics, culture, german

This might sound at first as an odd question, almost off-topic, but given that I'm looking for lyrics **in English** I think it still qualifies.

I'm watching episode 12 of the second season (S02E12) of "Pretty Little Liars" and about 27 minutes in, there's a scene where a music is played at Hanna's father's wedding.

At first, I thought it was Pachelbel's "Canon" being played on violins. Then, I realized it's the same tunes as the German national anthem, only slower. Baffled by that realization, I wonder what that song is and what the lyrics are.

Are the lyrics an exact translation of the anthem? Or is the text consisting of something totally different and unrelated?

Comment: Can you post a link where we can listen to this without paying for it or installing unfamiliar software?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has nothing to do with **learning** the English language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot find a convenient online source for this episode; but I may be able to back into an answer.

The tune of the *Deutschlandlied*—if that's the piece you're hearing— was originally composed by Haydn in 1797 as a birthday ode to Emperor Francis II of Austria, to a lyric which starts *Gott erhalte Franz den Kaiser*, "God save Emperor Francis".

It's a rousing tune and it was picked up not only by the author of the *Deutschland* lyric but also by protestant churches in the United States, where the tune goes under the name *Austria*. A hymn by Samuel Longfellow (brother of the more famous poet Henry Wadsworth Longfellow) which starts "Light of Ages and of nations" is often sung to this tune; but even better known is "Glorious things of Thee are spoken", by John Newton. The lyrics to both of these may be seen [here](http://www.hymnary.org/text/light_of_ages_and_of_nations). I would not be at all surprised if one of these is your song.